# Make TextView fit inside Layout on Android

Tags: android, textview, spannable

I have a FrameLayout which is square. I have a TextView inside the layout and an option for the user to increase/decrease the textSize. I want to limit the text increase option, when text is big enough to fill the entire FrameLayout. So if I start with something like 25sp, when the user reaches 40sp and TextView height gets over the FrameLayout height, I need to revert back to 39sp and forbid further increasing of text size. The source of the TextView is a spannable.

Here is how I did it so far.

On increase button I simply `setTextSize(currentValue + 1)` for each spannable fragment;

Because I don't know the "real" size of my TextView when I setText again, I have used

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = textView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
    //here I have the real sizes of the textView and if the height is too big, I simply
     setTextSize(currentValue - 1)
}
```

The downside is the visible operation of increasing text -> decreasing it again. So the user will see for like 100ms the text getting bigger and then reverting back. 
Is there a good way of handling this calculation so I can avoid actually increasing the text size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the answers received are great, but in my case I didn't find a proper way to detect how my TextView will actually wrap the text when Spannable was applied. In order to get the results I needed, I just added in my FrameLayout a new TextView with transparent font color. First I apply the changes to this invisible TextView, and if everything is ok, I propagate the changes to the actual visible TextView.

Comment: How do you detect that everything is working fine with transparent `TextView`?

Comment: I am applying first the spannable parameters (text size, font type..) to the transparent `TextView` and when `textView.getViewTreeObserver()` gets launched after the TextView is rendered, I can get the actual height/width/position on parent layout. Based on this values, I can decide either to apply the parameters or not to the actual visible `TextView`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using TextPaint and span classes to measure your text before actually changing the size. Measuring text requires splitting it onto spans. Then you should apply the spans to TextPaint object and ask it for text block dimensions.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.FontMetrics.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html

The task is quite complex, so in case of any troubles feel free to ask for more help. The code I'm using to measure text is long and uncommented, so I will maybe post it to google code in case any needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I am going to give it a try to see if it works.

Comment: I can't really figure it out. My bet would be like this: first recreate the spannable with all the attributes/size/typeface and then somehow draw it in a layout of the same size as my actual TextView and see what happens. I am thinking it would be easier to have an invisible TextView and apply to it all values first, and if everything ok, apply to the visible one.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv); 
String myText = tv.getText().toString();
char[] array = myText.toCharArray();
Paint paint = tv.getPaint();
Rect textBound = new Rect();
paint.getTextBounds(array, 0, array.length, textBound);
boolean enough = tv.getHeight() <= textBound.height()
            || tv.getWidth() <= textBound.width();
if(enough){
  // don't increase size further
}else{
// increase size
}
```

For animation you can do somthing like this:

```
final float proposed = tv.getTextSize() + 10;
final float orignal = tv.getTextSize();

if (enough) { 
    ObjectAnimator
                .ofFloat(this, "textSize", orignal, proposed, orignal)
                .setDuration(1000).start(); 
} else {
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "textSize", orignal, proposed)
                .setDuration(500).start(); 
}


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void setTextSize(float val) {
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, val);
}
```

Comment: For some fine tuning read @Zielony's comment, get `FontMatrics` from `Paint` object and do your customized calculations. But this code should work fine too.

Comment: Your `TextView` must be of fixed size otherwise `enough` variable will always be false.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer but I don't think it works when using spannable. Probably works great with plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this :

```
textView.getLayoutParams.height = screen.getWidth();
textView.requestLayout();
```